# Laravel - Wrap JSON response in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, laravel

I'm using the [jQuery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to deal with submitting my forms via AJAX.

When uploading files on old browsers that do not support file uploading via AJAX (Instead they use a hidden iframe) and returning a JSON response it is [recommended](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload) to wrap the response up in a textarea.

Now on my Laravel server side I want to return a JSON response wrapped up in a textarea if the request is not AJAX. Normally, to return a JSON response I would use `return Response::json($value);` but this doesn't allow me to wrap my response in a textarea.

**Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response**

```
public static function json($data = array(), $status = 200, array $headers = array(), $options = 0)
{
    if ($data instanceof ArrayableInterface)
    {
        $data = $data->toArray();
    }

    return new JsonResponse($data, $status, $headers, $options);
}
```

Is there a clean way in Laravel to return a JSON response wrapped in a textarea? I'm aware that I could simply return a `json_encode()`ed string wrapped in a textarea but I'm just looking for a potentially cleaner Laravel style approach.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a [Response Macro](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#macro) for this.

```
Response::macro('myjson', function($data = array(), $status = 200, array $headers = array(), $options = 0){
    $response = Response::json($data, $status, $headers, $options);
    if(!Request::ajax()){
        return Response::make('<textarea>'.$response->getContent().'</textarea>', $status, $headers);
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Usage: (exactly the same as `Response::json()`)

```
return Respones::myjson($value);
```

Comment: Fantastic! Is there anything Laravel can't do?!

Comment: The trick is that Laravel can't do anything but tries to be as extendable as possible so it's simple to add functionality :)

Comment: @lukasgeiter Do you put this code in your controller method?

Comment: @silkfire No you do it either in `app/start/global.php` (or in a file you include there) or in a service provider. (In Laravel 5 a service provider is definitely the preferred way). Please also check the docs as they cover that topic as well.

Comment: @lukasgeiter Hmm I always thought service providers are like classes. In this case all the user wants is a tiny method? Is there some way to make the method static? *confused*

Comment: Well service providers *are* classes. Classes to bootstrap and register things. Take a look at the [example in the documentation of L5](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#response-macros) that might clear things up :)

Comment: @lukasgeiter Thanks I'm still learning about Service Providers but have not found a good use for them yet. I've upgraded all my projects to L5 and love it so far :)

Comment: @silkfire You're welcome. Also make sure to read [this chapter](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers) in the docs about service providers if you haven't already.